# D3 Hover Over Changes When Data Changes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this D3 SVG bar chart:

```
http://tinyurl.com/cul7oyg
```

on the lower right hand side (you have to scroll down).  You can hover over the bars with no problem.  However, after clicking on the link at the bottom of the upper left hand box, I create a new bar chart with new data.  The mouseover now only works while hovering over the lines between the bars.  All I do with the link is to empty the contents of the div using: (d3.select("#barchart").html("") and then pass in a new smaller dataset to this function. The data is an array of objects.

```
function generateBarForData(data) {
var margin = {top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
    width = 750 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = data.length * 20 //500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width*.85])

//chart1.x =x
//chart1.y = y

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, height], 0);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("top");

var svg = d3.select("#barchart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return +d.netdonations_over_population_to_gdppercap_percentage; })).nice();
  y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }));

  bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return +d.netdonations_over_population_to_gdppercap_percentage <= 0 ? ("bar negative " + d.name) : ("bar positive " + d.name); })
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(Math.min(0, +d.netdonations_over_population_to_gdppercap_percentage)); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.name); })
      .attr("width", function(d) { return Math.abs(x(+d.netdonations_over_population_to_gdppercap_percentage) - x(0)); })
      .attr("height", y.rangeBand()).on('mouseover', function(d,i) {
        //barChartSelectOneCountry(this) //rect
        selectBarChartCountryWithClear(d, this)  //mouseover(d)

      }).style("stroke","white")

chart1.svg = svg
chart1.x = x
chart1.y = y

svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("text").text(function(d) {
        return d;
   }).attr("class", function(d) {return +d.netdonations_over_population_to_gdppercap_percentage <= 0 ? "recipient" : "donor"})
   .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return y(d.name)+ y.rangeBand();
        //return i * (height / data.length)+30;
   }).attr("x", function(d) {
         return x(0) //x(Math.min(0, +d.netdonations_over_population_to_gdppercap_percentage));
   }).text(function(d) {
        //return y(d) + y.rangeBand() / 2;
        return d.name + " " + d.netdonations_over_population_to_gdppercap_percentage;
        }).style("font-size","14px").attr("dx", 3).attr("dy", "-0.45em")


  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
    .append("line")
      .attr("x1", x(0))
      .attr("x2", x(0))
      .attr("y2", height);
}
```

Comment: "mouseover now only works while hovering over the lines between the bars". It is very slow to update but reacts to hover on the bar (after having changed graph to No Donor countries - green lines)

Comment: It doesn't react if you hover over the text. Check out the pointer-event attribute http://themousepotatowebsite.co.za/pointer-events-none/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mouseover event listener doesn't trigger whenever the mouse is over the text part of the bar. That's because the text captures it. The trick is to stop the text part from capturing the mouse events. See http://themousepotatowebsite.co.za/pointer-events-none/ for guidelines.

In your CSS

```
.text { pointer-event: none }
```

Comment: That site described that property use as experimental and it also causes problems when you actually want to query the DOM.  I figured the best option for me was just to add a mousover event to the text itself, in addition to the bars. The only thing is that when the cursor is over the text, it doesn't display a pointer but a vertical line.  Do you know what could be the cause of that?

Comment: If you are not comfortable using pointer-event, a better strategy is to group your text and bar and attach the event listener to the group.

Comment: for the cursor display on text, you can always apply a css class forcing the cursor to be pointer for the text element